# Is this method of static file serving safe in node.js? (potential security hole?)

Tags: node.js

I want to create the simplest node.js server to serve static files.

Here's what I came up with:

```
fs = require('fs');
server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/' + req.url));
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Clearly this would map `http://localhost:8080/index.html` to `project_dir/public/index.html`, and similarly so for all other files.

My one concern is that someone could abuse this to access files outside of `project_dir/public`.  Something like this, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/../../sensitive_file.txt
```

I tried this a little bit, and it wasn't working.  But, it seems like my browser was removing the ".." itself.  Which leads me to believe that someone could abuse my poor little node.js server.

I know there are npm packages that do static file serving.  But I'm actually curious to write my own here.  So my questions are:

1. Is this safe?
2. If so, why?  If not, why not?
3. And, if further, if not, what is the "right" way to do this?  My one constraint is I don't want to have to have an if clause for each possible file, I want the server to serve whatever files I throw in a directory.

Comment: The best thing to do is to parse the path using a system library, and ensure it stays "sandboxed" within a given directory. What, precisely, do you want to allow people access to?

Comment: Yep, browsers will remove extra `..`s before they send the request. However, other tools -- `curl`, for example, or even `telnet` if you don't mind crafting the HTTP request by hand -- can send leading `..`s, so your server does indeed need to defend against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it's not safe.
2. For the reason you mention.
3. Use [`fs.realpath()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_callback) or [`fs.realpathSync()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_path) and check that the normalized path points to where you want it to.

Answer (score -3):

It is not safe so use something like that:

```
if (req.url.indexOf('..') !== -1) {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
}
```

PS: by the way, use readFile instead of readFileSync and watch for errors... your implementation is too bad even for an example -_-

Comment: You could have said that much nicer! And not to mention that you could have explained to him WHY its not the best practice to use `readFileSync` outside of initialization code.
I also fail to see where you answer the actual, legit, question.